# "Can't Write" error on xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.forms

Has Someone already seen this error?
It happend after I Installed Geolocator in the Android project of my Forms project...

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Can't write [C:\Users\Indefinido\AppData\Local\Temp\mainDexClasses-10575.tmp.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Indefinido\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat$JbMr1ViewCompatImpl.class]))    neoFly_Montana.Android  C:\montana\neoFly_Montana\neoFly_Montana\neoFly_Montana.Android\CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST

Comment: do NOT post errors and code as images!!!  Please take the time to paste and format the text so that it's readable and indexable by search engines.  Also consider searching before posting - there are multiple hits on "duplicate zip entry" already that may be useful

Comment: Thank u very much '-'

Comment: What's your `Geolocator` version?

Comment: Try update your nuget packages to latest.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It happend after I installed Geolocator in the Android project.

I think you installed the latest `Geolocator` nuget package, and the `Geolocator` package contains some other dependency, like `support.v4`.

> Duplicate zip entry

After you installed the `Geolocator` nuget package, some library used in your project has two version, this may produce this problem.

Update you nuget package to latest so that the package version is same, this problem could be solved.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was it!
Thank u!